# The Image in cell does not appear

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, alamofire

I'm using alamofire to get url image from json file, and want to display the image I get from json to imageview in cell. I'm new to swift and swift networking.

My code on MainCollectionViewController:

```
private let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"

class MainCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

var result:String = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



}
override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}


override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of items
    return 1
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MainCollectionViewCell

    Alamofire.request(.POST, "URL That Contain JSON").responseJSON { response in

        if let value = response.result.value {

            let json = JSON(value)

            let data = json["data"].arrayValue

            self.result = data[0]["image"].stringValue

            print(self.result)

        }
    }

    let imageName = (result)
    cell.mainImageView.image = UIImage(named:imageName)

    return cell
}
```

And the image outlet is in MainCollectionViewCell:

```
class MainCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var mainImageView: UIImageView!
}
```

The build succeded but the image does not appear, it shows cell with no image inside.

Answer (score 2):

Alamofire is still requesting for JSON but you have your `UIImageView` updated before the response arrives. Before `Alamofire` can come back with response, your code will try to update `UIImageView` with result which has not yet been received making your `Result` string still an empty string just like you declared on top.That is why you are getting empty `UIImageView`.

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MainCollectionViewCell

Alamofire.request(.POST, "URL That Contain JSON").responseJSON { response in
    if let value = response.result.value {
        let json = JSON(value)
        let data = json["data"].arrayValue
        self.result = data[0]["image"].stringValue
        print(self.result)
        let imageName = (result)
        cell.mainImageView.image = UIImage(named:imageName)
    }
}
return cell
}
```

It is however not a popular practice to make load request when cell is updating.

Comment: I assume you are getting url string for that image. If so, change url to image through NSData. You can also just use UIImage+AfNetworking.swift class that you can download to get image from the url in response.

Answer (score 0):

Responce running in diferent thread so at that time "result"  doesn't have data. try to load after the responce will solve your problem .

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()    
    getImage()
}
 func getImage()
 {
    Alamofire.request(.POST, "URL That Contain JSON").responseJSON { response in

    if let value = response.result.value {

        let json = JSON(value)

        let data = json["data"].arrayValue

        self.result = data[0]["image"].stringValue

        print(self.result)

    }
//reload collection view 
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

let cell =   collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MainCollectionViewCell
  let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: result, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
                    let decodedimage = UIImage(data: decodedData!)

cell.mainImageView.image = decodedimage
return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you didn't register your nib.

```
self.collectionView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "MainCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "MainCollectionViewCell")
```

Put this code on `ViewDidLoad`

Answer (score 0):

you are just getting image url not image from the server so firstly you should be download image then set in mainImageView.